Transformation to replace a Material derivative with a spatial derivative
In the technical paper referenced below, Gringarten et al. claim that the transient energy transport equation  in a planar conduit (Eq. 1 in their paper)
$$
\rho c  \Bigg[ \frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial t}+v\frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial z}\Bigg]=Q(t)
$$
can be reduced with the transformation $ t^\prime=t-(z/v)$ to Eq (A1) in their appendix
$$
\rho c v  \frac{\partial T(z,t^\prime)}{\partial z}=Q(t^\prime)
$$
Despite attempting all sorts of manipulations with the chain rule, I simply cannot derive their Eq. (A1) - how does the material derivative get replaced entirely with a spatial derivative in terms of the transformed time?!
Any pointers on how they did this would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.
Gringarten, A. C., Witherspoon, P. A., and Ohnishi, Y., 1975, “Theory of Heat Extraction from Fractured Hot Dry Rock”, Journal of Geophysical Research, Vol 80, N0. 8, 1975.
I've included a snapshot of the relevant equations from their paper below:

